# Scan a barcode and then open a website or file - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, barcode, barcode-scanner

I´m trying to open a file (or website) after scanning my barcode. My barcode is showed into tkinter terminal, but I don´t know how to create an action to open a file or website.
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

class Window(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.geometry('100x20')

        self.code = ''

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="?")
        self.label.pack()

        self.bind('<Key>', self.get_key)

    def get_key(self, event):

        if event.char in '0123456789':
            self.code += event.char
            #print('>', self.code)
            self.label['text'] = self.code

        elif event.keysym == 'Return':
            #print('result:', self.code)
            showinfo('Code', self.code)
```

## --- main ---

```
win = Window()
win.mainloop()
```

Can someone help me how I can handle it. How can I create an interface or button to open a file / website?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Opening websites:

```
import webbrowser # pre-installed with python
url = 'www.google.co.uk'
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Opening files (Windows):

```
import os # pre installed 
os.startfile('file directory') # e.g "G:/Documents/School/image.png"
```

For more details and methods regarding the webbrowser and os modules check out:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Heres a mini UI that takes a barcode and either opens a file or webpage:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__ (self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()

        b = StringVar()
        b.set("Enter barcode")

        self.barcode = Entry(self, textvariable = b)
        self.barcode.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='n')

        self.submit = Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.get_barcode)
        self.submit.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='s')

    def get_barcode(self):
        barcode = int(self.barcode.get())

        if barcode == 000:
            url = "www.google.co.uk"
            webbrowser.open(url)
        elif barcode == 111:
            os.startfile("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe")
        else:
            print("invalid barcode or something")


root= Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Obviously i haven't added any validation, but you can do this easily and perhaps even add some pop-up dialogues for the validation.

Comment: Note i imported * from tkinter so you will have to add tk. to variables from the tkinter module as you imported tkinter as tk

Comment: Many thanks Rodriguez. The code is great. It is working!!